# Identifiying windows users in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to identify incoming user into Oracle in order to give them access right according to their identity (FGAC). Users are located in different domain's. which means that they might have identical system username (windows userename).

I have been trying to use the Environment context variable sys_context('userenv', 'var') where I get the Domain name (f.ex. SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','HOST') and SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER')) but I seem to get different result's depending on the connection method.

Are there any other means of getting users true identity I can explore?

Comment: Can you expand on the different results you're getting and the different connection methods you're experimenting with?  Are you connecting via a three-tier application?  Or are you connecting directly from the client machine to the database, in which case I'm not sure what different connection methods you're thinking about.

Comment: I am using primarily SQL*Net and ODAC (http://www.devart.com/odac/) to connect to then database. 
When I use SQL*Net :
SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','HOST') reurns "domain\username"
but with ODAC I get only "username"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which variable you should use but you may want to look at `select * from v$session` to help you pick one.

Comment: I have tried to use v$session but with equally inconsistent results. I would expect the fields OSUSER and MACHINE vould give the desierd results but as you can see from the listing belowe the result depends on the program connected. #OSUSER || MACHINE || PROGRAM  #CENTER1\andrjesg || CENTER1\WIS0968 || Kria.exe #steinarth || wisinf51 || JDBC Thin Client #CENTER1\andrjesg || CENTER1\WIS0968 || sqlnavigator.exe #andrjesg || CENTER1\WIS0968 || Kria-ODAC.exe Hope the table listing makes sense to you, two vertical bars betwean fields and a # for a new record:)

Answer (score 0):

If you're basing FGAC on OS_USER environment variable, you're truly not securing the data. OS_USER isn't a credential passed to Oracle, it's just a string that can be manipulated by an attacker.